# Quebrando string a partir de um caracter

Tags: python, string, pandas

Dentro do meu *dataframe*, uma das colunas possui informações separadas por virgula, gostaria de eliminar tudo dentro da *string* que estivesse após a primeira virgula.

Segue o código que estou tentando utilizar:

```
df_movies = df_movies[df_movies["country"].str.split(",")]
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte código de erro:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 3):

O código que tentou não faz sentido.

```
df_movies = df_movies[df_movies["country"].str.split(",")]
```

Você busca a *string* que possui os valores separados por vírgula e separa os valores nesse caractere. Isto é, se receber a *string* `'a,b,c'` você construirá a lista `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Depois disso você tenta acessar o *dataframe* a partir dessa lista, o que seria basicamente:

```
df_movies[['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

O que isso deveria fazer?

Se a ideia é buscar o primeiro valor antes da vírgula, você não precisa acessar novamente o *dataframe*. Basta definir a lógica de mapeamento dos valores e aplicá-la na sua coluna:

```
df_movies['country'] = df_movies['country'].apply(
    lambda values: values.split(',')[0]
)
```

Assim, a coluna `'country'` possuirá apenas o primeiro nome da lista.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria! Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa `.split` ele transforma a string em um array separado pelo caracter que você usou.
neste caso acho que poderia fazer assim:

```
In [6]: minha_string = "antesdavirgula,depoisdavirgula"                                                                                                                                                            

In [7]: antes_da_virgula, *_ = minha_string.split(",")[0]                                                                                                                                                              

In [8]: antes_da_virgula                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[8]: 'antesdavirgula'
```